# How do I remove the extended atributes visualization from my OSX terminal?

Tags: shell, terminal, osx, macintosh

To day I opened my terminal and it looks like:

```
user@MacBook-Pro-de-User:~$ ls
total 8
drwxr-xr-x+  5 user   170B Oct  3 16:57 Public/
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+  3 user   102B Oct  3 16:57 Pictures/
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+  3 user   102B Oct  3 16:57 Music/
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+  3 user   102B Oct  3 16:57 Movies/
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------@ 49 user   1.6K Oct  6 12:09 Library/
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------   3 user   102B Oct  6 13:44 VirtualBox VMs/
-rw-r--r--   1 user   2.9K Oct  7 08:14 Vagrantfile
drwxr-xr-x   8 user   272B Oct  8 22:44 Jupyter/
drwxr-xr-x   5 user   170B Oct  8 23:04 polyglot_data/
drwx------+  5 user   170B Oct 11 08:11 Desktop/
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------+  2 user    68B Oct 11 08:36 Downloads/
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwx------@  3 user   102B Oct 11 08:38 Google Drive/
```

How can I return the old visualization style?:

```
user@MacBook-Pro-de-User:~$ ls
Public Pictures Music Movies Library
```

Comment: Do you have an alias set up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, an alias for `ls` has been set up for your account, either by the sysadmin or by someone else using your account.

Search the files `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` for a line that looks like

```
alias ls='ls <some-options-here>'
```

and remove it.

If it has been put as a system-wide setting, you'll need to have superuser access and edit `/etc/bashrc` or `/etc/profile`.

Alternatively, you can run at any moment the non-aliased command **ls** via either

```
/bin/ls
```

or

```
\ls
```

Comment: @tumbleweed If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Sure, the site did not allowed me, for time reasons;)